# Computer Craft modem.open( ) command giving me "attempt to index ? (a nil value)"

Tags: lua, modem, computercraft

I am new to Computer Craft, and I want to get started using Wireless Modems.

```
local modem = peripheral.wrap("top")
local channel = 1
modem.open(channel)
```

I have the code above, and when I try to run the `modem.open()` command, it gives me a message saying "attempt to call index ? (a nil value)". I know that many people have had this error before. I have searched through questions and tutorials and followed their exact code or instructions, but none of them have worked and I cannot find any other questions with this error message showing up from this command. My modem is on top of my computer.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is that your entire code?

Comment: Also, if you want to use wireless modems, you can use the rednet API

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wireless modems, considering using the rednet API.

```
rednet.open("top")
```

Configures your computer for sending messages wirelessly. Go to
[the computercraft wiki](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Rednet_(API)) for the full documentation

You can send messages using `rednet.send()` or `rednet.broadcast()` and receive messages through `sender, message = rednet.receive()`